# Add share button under product in prestashop

Tags: php, share, prestashop

I got a social network share button from add to any. I want to place it under all my products.

I edited product.tpl in my theme and add addToAny code given by them. But its not showing there.

```
<!-- number of item in stock -->
            {if ($display_qties == 1 && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE && $product->available_for_order)}
            <p id="pQuantityAvailable"{if $product->quantity <= 0} style="display: none;"{/if}>
                <span id="quantityAvailable">{$product->quantity|intval}</span>
                <span {if $product->quantity > 1} style="display: none;"{/if} id="quantityAvailableTxt">{l s='item in stock'}</span>
                <span {if $product->quantity == 1} style="display: none;"{/if} id="quantityAvailableTxtMultiple">{l s='items in stock'}</span>
            </p>

<div>
//Adding my addToAny share code here
</div>

            {/if}
            <!-- Out of stock hook -->
            {if !$allow_oosp}
            <p id="oosHook"{if $product->quantity > 0} style="display: none;"{/if}>
                {$HOOK_PRODUCT_OOS}
            </p>
            {/if}
```

Comment: it would help if you could show your code up to this point.

Comment: What can I show? I am adding <p>text</p> in product.tpl file and its not displaying it in browser.

Comment: try changing the cache settings. smarty wont compile until you change the cache settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In admin panel
goto --> preference --> performance --> select Force compile to yes. Smarty wont compile until you set it to yes.